# my imageloder not change image if new image same name

Tags: android

below is my imageloader code which work fine if new image are diffrent name but if new image are same name then is not change images show old image only suppose i have image name myimage is display perfectly  if i add new image in url with same name and delete previous my code again show previous image not show new image due to cache what is problem in this code help me please

```
    ImageLoader2 imgLoader;
    String url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");
                imgLoader.DisplayImage(url1, img1);






  public class ImageLoader2 {

MemoryCache2 memoryCache=new MemoryCache2();
FileCache2 fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new    
WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader2(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache2(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
 }

 final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
 public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
 {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
 }

 private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
 {
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
 }

 private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
 {
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
           memoryCache.clear();
       return null;
    }
  }

 //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
 private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
 }

 //Task for the queue
 private class PhotoToLoad
 {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
 }

   class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
 }

  boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
 }

 //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
 class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
 {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
   }

 public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

 }





         public class MemoryCache2 {

 private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
 private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));
 private long size=0;//current allocated size
 private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

  public MemoryCache2(){
    //use 25% of available heap size
    setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
 }

 public void setLimit(long new_limit){
    limit=new_limit;
    Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
 }

 public Bitmap get(String id){
    try{
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;

        return cache.get(id);
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
 }

 public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
    try{
        if(cache.containsKey(id))
            size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
        cache.put(id, bitmap);
        size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
        checkSize();
    }catch(Throwable th){
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private void checkSize() {
    Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
    if(size>limit){
        Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
            size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
            iter.remove();
            if(size<=limit)
                break;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
    }
}

 public void clear() {
    try{

        cache.clear();
        size=0;
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap==null)
        return 0;
    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
}
 }





     private File cacheDir;

  public FileCache2(Context context){
    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if  (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals
 (android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new   
 File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TTImages_cache");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url){
    //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
    //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

 }

  public void clear(){
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    if(files==null)
        return;
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
 }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given it already:

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

As per your code given below line:

```
 String url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");
```

Instead of below line:

```
 **imgLoader.DisplayImage(url1, img1);**
```

Replace it to:

```
androidAQuery.id(image1).image(url1, true, true,default icon(optional));

Initialize aQuery in your onCreate():

private AQuery androidAQuery; androidAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());
```

Comment: it will automatically compress bitmap like image loader? what i write in optional? default android icon?

Comment: what is image1 in this code

androidAQuery.id(image1).image(url1, true, true,default icon(optional));

Comment: Your ImageView, I have seen it in your code: 
String url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");
                imgLoader.DisplayImage(url1, img1);

Comment: Default icon is for, when you image is under process to download, till that time one default image will shown there, but when your image will be download at that time, it will replace it with original.

Comment: androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, true, true,default icon(optional));    default and  (optional show error

Comment: this line show error

 androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, true, true,default icon(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
default and Rdrawable.icon shoew error

Comment: androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, true, true,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Comment: androidAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());

Comment: i used ur code but is again show cache image what is the meaning of true tue in ur code???

Comment: androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, true, true,default icon(optional))

Comment: make both values to false.

Comment: this code works flawlessly thnx for that. I implemented it in a listview and I want to show the previously downloaded image till the new one is downloaded and replace as soon as it is done..how to do it?

Comment: androidAQuery.id(image1).image(url1, true, true,default icon(optional)); //this line will do it. the 2 parameters true,true means, it will cache the images in memory and file, so everytime it will not download the image but second time it will show from memory directly.

Comment: yes but as the url is same all the time so I dont know when image in the url changes. So when the list is scrolled I want to show the last present image till the new one is downloaded as I am downloading the images each time the list is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for Image loading:

Use Android Query. AQuery is giving option for cahce enable or disables and its quite fast as well as more accurate then any ImageLoader class.

You will find aQuery jar file from below link:

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

private AQuery androidAQuery;
androidAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());

androidAQuery.id(your imageview).image(your image value, true, true,default icon(optional));

Comment: this is the working example, you need to put just 2 lnes of code to image download and display.

androidAQuery.id(your imageview).image(your downloadable ImageURL, memory cache(true or false),file cache(true or false),default icon(optional));

You just need to download jar file and set it on Build path of your project and you are done.

Comment: write programiclaly what u say im confuse

Comment: private AQuery androidAQuery; 
androidAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());

androidAQuery.id(your imageview).image(your image value, true, true,default icon(optional));

I have wrote it programatically already, you only have to write this 2 lines of code, at where you want to show your image.

Comment: Instead of this line:

 String url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");
                imgLoader.DisplayImage(url1, img1);

Write below code:

private AQuery androidAQuery; androidAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());

androidAQuery.id(image1).image(url1, true, true);

Comment: where is aQuery library??

Comment: set on my code how do i change in text mode is so confuseable write on my code what u say?

Comment: androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, true, true,default icon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)); default and icon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)); show error

Comment: The method image(String, boolean, boolean, int, int) in the type AbstractAQuery<AQuery> is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean, boolean, int)

Comment: right the answer and make it up arrow, so other people can benefit of this.